# Locally Hosting Web applications in Ubuntu

Tags: web-applications, ubuntu

How do I host my Web Application files in ubuntu locally?

I m used to working on Windows and in there we put all the files in the wwwroot folder and then configure the IIS and the run the app on localhost:8080

I wish to do the same in Ubuntu 12.04 (if the version makes any difference do let me know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the answer myself. We need to install the apache2 in Ubuntu to get the localhost started.

This [link](http://maketecheasier.com/install-and-configure-apache-in-ubuntu/2011/03/09) helps out.

Comment: whether or not you have to install Apache depends on how you installed Ubuntu. Sounds like you might benefit from running tasksel in your bash shell... ubuntu@ubuntu$ sudo tasksel.. if it is not installed then ubuntu@ubuntu$ sudo apt-get install tasksel

Comment: ia m running ubuntu on my VMware. I google `tasksel` but I am not sure how will it help me?

Comment: Tasksel is what you would run in the bash shell to get into an installer that will install Apache and many other things. It is far easier and I mention it because it seems as though you are not too familiar with Linux/Unix environments. Basically you will want to use package management in some form to install and manage software. For you that means Synaptic, Tasksel and / or dpkg.. or Ubuntu Software Center in applications. If you explain more about what you want to do I may have more help for you.

Comment: well basically i wanted to run my web app locally like we do on windows, by putting the folder in wwwroot and configure them on IIS. So needed to do the same. Once i configured the apache using synaptic it is working fine now.
Ya u r right i am new to Ubuntu, so playing around.

Comment: Well you're on your way. I am also a VMWare user and have a couple Linux variants in VMWare all the time. Ubuntu runs well, but you will not be able to get 3D graphics support using vmware-tools in an Ubuntu guest. Just a heads up before you start banging your head trying. Good luck..

Comment: Thanks @apesa Also can u help me with a predicament I m facing in Stackoverflow. Few of my questions were downvoted and Now I am not able to ask any questions. I don't know what to do, can pls help me out. As u know I am new, can u guide me in what I did wrong?

Comment: Sure, StackOverFlow should really be the last resort you use after you have tried several things on your own. So when you post your well thought out and well constructed question on Stack you would also explain what you tried and show us your example. When people then read your question and see you have tried a couple things we are then much more inclined to help. When it looks like you have not really tried or have not posted a well thought out question you get down voted. Do it enough and you end up restricted.

Comment: Oh but now how can i reverse it?

Comment: It looks like you got hammered on that django question. My advice is to NOT repost someones comment as your answer. Since it is in fact an answer and you obviously are in the dark I voted that answer up so it may or may not enable you to post. But that is what needs to happen.

Comment: But I only posted the answer with the guys name so that I can mark it as a answer for anyone looking for the same issue. I also left his name so that ppl knew who gave the answer. Thanks for the up vote. Would deleting that make a difference?

Comment: Right, I see that. But you posted the answer logged in as you. So in fact you answered your own question. You never know who is going to subjectively down vote. To me it's no big deal, but I am not the community. Give it a couple days and when you have a question try to post. But you can't just post everything you have a question about, you have to allow time for learning on your own. Google works very well.

Comment: I wouldn't touch it. You already got voted up a lot based on a comment or two.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu that location is /var/www. There should already be an index.html file in that location. This will work as is if you have not installed other web based apps like tomcat or jboss as those installations may have modified the config for the web server.

If you're going to be developing web based applications and want it set up locally for dev and debug there is a better way using Eclipse and MySQL or your DB choice, but your post does not indicate what you really want to do.

Comment: I did not even have the apache2 installed so was not able to see `/var/www`